# Какое ругательство скрыл Радищев в выражении "кан... бес"?

Tags: значение-слов, литература, обсценная-лексика, историческое-словообразование

В [книге](https://books.google.com/books/about/%D0%9F%D1%83%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%88%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D0%B8%D0%B7_%D0%9F%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B1.html?hl=ru&id=xK3MwuPGazcC) Радищева "Путешествие из Петербурга в Москву" есть такая фраза:

> Тысяча голосов на меня подымаются; ругают меня всякими мерзкими названиями: мошенник, плут, кан... бес, и пр., и пр.

Что значит "кан... бес"?

Comment: _Что значит "кан... бес"?_ === По-моему, абсолютно точно на этот вопрос мог бы ответить только Радищев. Увы, его не спросишь...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Не думаю, что это ругательство.
В [других источниках](https://ilibrary.ru/text/1850/p.14/index.html) это предложение имеет такой вид:

> Тысяча голосов на меня подымаются; ругают меня всякими мерзкими названиями: мошенник, плут, кан... бес... и пр. и пр.

Так что речь идет о значении слова "кан".
Словарь Даля:
[кан](https://diclist.ru/slovar/dalya/k/kan.html)
м. канка ж. ряз. тул. тамб. (немецк. Наhn?) индейский петух и курица, канок, каныш вор. донск. пырин и пырка, дурак, дурка; курыль, каплун (пен. вм. калкун). Каненок, каня м. канята, канчата мн. индеячьи цыплята. Канячий, к кану относящ. Канина ж. канячье мясо.

[Словарь русских народных говоров](https://iling.spb.ru/dictionaries/srng/13.pdf) (стр. 34):
**Кан**, а, м. Индюк Тул., **1820** Ряз. Тамб. *Кан как надуется, хвост свой распустит, так сразу вдвое больше станет, важный такой.* **Моск.**

**Дополнение**
Вот что нашлось [в примечаниях](http://books.e-heritage.ru/book/10083809) Л. Б. Светлова (стр. 524):
101 Кан... бес... — каналья, бестия.

Comment: Да, действительно, на Википедии тоже такое написание, но чо-то я сомневаюсь что Радищев столь аккуратный в пунктуации вдруг взял и начал в перечислении использовать многоточия вместо запятых. Выглядит странно. Но версия хорошая, покопаю её, спасибо!

Comment: Ой, только что увидел дополнение) Значит и правда слова каналья и бестия по каким-то причинам были скрыты многоточками. Ещё раз спасибо!

Comment: «На» Википедии? Это почему же?

Comment: @shampar, что конкретно почему? Почему использовано "на"? Если нужно аргументировать, то я не знаю, просто как-то так вышло само: на тостере, на хабре, на learnjs, на википедии, на украине)

Comment: Ну тогда и «в пунктуации» — см. вторую строчку комментария — надо причесать «правильно».

Comment: @shampar, нет, не надо причёсывать, всё так как должно быть